# Audio kit is slowly

Tags: audiokit

I am  trying to use the library to get data from Bluetooth device and play it live as I hit the button .

The Bluetooth input is fast and I get the input at the moment I hit the button but the library is a bottle neck , it takes about 80-100ms or more, till I hear the sound.

Also, if I hit twice fast he play only the first and wait for it to end till I can play next note.

What is the best way to use it to play live instrument ? this is my implelemnation:

```
First I load, then every time I have Bluetooth input, I play :

{

    do {
        let file = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "A.wav", baseDir: .resources)
        player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: file)
        player.looping = false
        AudioKit.output = player
        AudioKit.start()



    }
    catch let error1 as NSError
    {

    } catch {

    }

}


func play()
{
         player.play()
}
```

Comment: Could you try the new AKPlayer in the develop branch of AudioKit instead?